# Creating list of lists and skipping elements in Python

Tags: list, python-3.x

How can I create a list of list using `[x for x in input]` (where input is a list of strings) and skip elements if they satisfy certain condition? For example, this is the list of lists:

```
[['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], ['abc', 'd_f', '+hi'], ['_bc', 'def', 'ghi']]
```

and this should be the output -- with skipped elements containing either '_' or '+':

```
[['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], ['abc'], ['def', 'ghi']]
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/filtering_lists.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a sub-list comprehension:

```
[[item for item in sub if not any(char in item for char in '_+')] for sub in input]
```

which is a simplified version of:

```
result = []
for sub in input:
    result.append([])
    for item in sub:
        should_add = True
        for char in '_+':
            if char in item:
                should_add = False
                break
        if should_add:
            result[-1].append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty similar to the other answer except tests if the string contains only alpha numeric characters as opposed to specifically `'_'` and `'+'`. Loops through each sub list then the strings in each sub list.

```
filtered = [[s for s in l if s.isalpha()] for l in lists]

print(filtered)

[['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], ['abc'], ['def', 'ghi']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another short version using a *set*:

```
stuff= [['abc', 'def', 'ghi'], ['abc', 'd_f', '+hi'], ['_bc', 'def', 'ghi']]
unwanted = {'+', '-'}
filtered = [[item for item in s if not set(s) & unwanted] for s in stuff]
```